# Duplicado en RecyclerView y la llamada a una funcion de un fragmento

Tags: android, kotlin

Hola intento hacer que al seleccionar un elemento del recyclerview, la informacion de ese elemento se vaya a una funcion que esta en el fragmento (lo que hace la funcion es enviar el item seleccionado a la base de datos de firebase) el problema es que cuando selecciono un elemento se duplican en los recyclerview, si me envia el elemento seleccionado a la base de datos.
El objetivo de mi problema es
Resolver el duplicado de los elementos

GRACIAS POR SU AYUDA DE ANTEMANO

Codigo del adaptador

```
class JugadoresAdapter( val context: JugadoresFragment, private val listaEquipos: MutableList<Equipo>, ) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<JugadoresAdapter.JugadoresViewHolder>() {

private lateinit var mListener: onItemClickListener
var row_index = 0

interface onItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
}
fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: onItemClickListener){
    mListener = listener
}

class JugadoresViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val tvNombreJug: TextView = itemView.tvNameJugador
    val imgUser: ImageView = itemView.fotoPerfil
    val tvContenedor: LinearLayout = itemView.contenedorJugadores

    fun asignarInformacion(equipo: Equipo) {
        /*itemView.setOnClickListener {

        }*/
    }

}
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): JugadoresViewHolder {


    return JugadoresAdapter.JugadoresViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_jugadores_equipos, parent, false)
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: JugadoresAdapter.JugadoresViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.tvNombreJug.text = listaEquipos[position].correo
    Picasso.get().load(listaEquipos[position].imgPerfil).into(holder.imgUser)


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        row_index = position
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        (context).updateButtonColor(
                listaEquipos[position].correo.toString(),
                listaEquipos[position].imgPerfil.toString()
        )
    })
    if (row_index === position) {
        holder.tvContenedor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4D00FF"))

    } else {
        holder.tvContenedor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))

    }
    holder.asignarInformacion(listaEquipos[position])
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return listaEquipos.size
}
```

}

Codigo del fragmento

```
class JugadoresFragment: Fragment()  {
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    Log.d(Constraints.TAG, "onAttach")
    super.onAttach(context)
}
private lateinit var emailUsuario:String
private lateinit var salaCreada:String
private lateinit var cualSala:String
private lateinit var entra:String
private lateinit var nombre:String
private lateinit var imgPerfil:String
private val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
var index:Int = 0

val listaJugadores = mutableListOf<Equipo>()
var adaptador = JugadoresAdapter(this@JugadoresFragment,listaJugadores)

val listaJugadores2 = mutableListOf<Equipo>()
val adaptador2 = JugadoresAdapter(this@JugadoresFragment,listaJugadores2)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jugadores, container, false)

    val myReVJug = rootView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvEquipo1)
    val myReVJug2 = rootView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvEquipo2)


    myReVJug.adapter = adaptador
    myReVJug2.adapter = adaptador2
    adaptador.setOnItemClickListener(object : JugadoresAdapter.onItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Has presionado un elemento", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })

    adaptador2.setOnItemClickListener(object : JugadoresAdapter.onItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Has presionado un elemento", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })

    emailUsuario = activity?.intent?.getStringExtra("email").toString()
    //adaptador = RespuestasAdapter(listaMensajes, {index -> deleteItem(index)}, {index -> modifiedItems(index)})
    //nombre = activity?.intent?.getStringExtra("name").toString()
    imgPerfil = activity?.intent?.getStringExtra("fileName").toString()

    cualSala()

    return rootView
}
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

}

private fun recibirEquipo1() {
    val respuestasRef2 = db.getReference("salas/" + cualSala + "/equipos")
    respuestasRef2.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            //listaSala.clear()
            for (snap in snapshot.children) {
                val equipo: Equipo = snap.getValue(Equipo::class.java) as Equipo
                // val equipoComparar = snap.child("equipo").value
                if (equipo.equipo == "equipo1") {
                    listaJugadores.add(equipo)

                }

            }
            if (listaJugadores.size > 0) {
                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }

    })
}
public fun updateButtonColor(
        correo: String, fotoPerfil: String,
) {

    var correo = correo.toString()
    var foto = fotoPerfil.toString()


    val objetoJugador = User(
            "",
            "",
            correo,
            foto,
            "",
            ""
    )
    // update button's color here
    //de aqui voy a mandar a subir la pregunta seleccionada para que la lean los jugadores
    enviarJugador(objetoJugador)
}

private fun enviarJugador(user: User) {
    val chatRef = db.getReference("salas/" + cualSala + "/jugadorActivoE1")
    chatRef.removeValue()
    val mensajeFirebase = chatRef.push()
    user.uid = mensajeFirebase.key ?: ""
    chatRef.setValue(user)
}
```

}

Comment: Parece que estás inicializando dos veces el onClickListener del item... una cuando llamas a asignarInformacion y hacer populate de la vista, y otra cuando creas la instancia del ViewHolder, yo borraría la que está dentro de la función

Comment: El código no se entiende. Hay funciones definidas que nunca se usan y llamas otras que no se ve que estén definidas. Lo más importante es que no muestras en que momento recibes los datos, entonces tu problema no se puede reproducir. Deberías [edit] tu pregunta y proporcionar un [mre]